# How to change MIME Type with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mime-types, mechanize

The actual content of this site is an image (http://cf.ccdn.es/e_1/CB34A36F787E8E77C4F29B7B8366CA975623AADB85F9FFBD74144AAF871C0DDCEA11C7A4C38903CDA63D620BB6190F68), but since it doesn't seem to be formatted like one I have problems handling it in my Rails application; I interprets the page as html instead of an image because of its MIME type. How could I change this so it will get recognized correctly?

I know that I can do something like this:

```
MIME::Types.type_for('jpg').first
```

which will give me the correct type, but how do I implement it in a way that it will overwrite the existing one when I request it with Mechanize?

If this is a little unclear: How can the above "image" be converted to something that gets recognized as an image?

Comment: Can you add how you're currently getting the image in your rails app?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
send_file [image location], type: "image/jpeg", disposition: "inline"
```